# printing multiple keys of each json object using generator expressions

Tags: python, json

I am using this API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts to list all the posts like this,

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
```

My code,

```
session  = requests.Session()
payload = session.request("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", timeout = 30).json()

print(payload)
```

Now I wanted to sort all the objects by `id`,

```
d = sorted(payload, key=operator.itemgetter("id"))
print(d)
```

Now if i want to sort by length of title instead,

i don't know how to use `operator` to provide `len(title)` as key is it possible?

Using generator expression with `for` loop instead of `key`,

```
d = sorted(len(value["title"]) for value in payload)
print(d)
```

Output,

```
[12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 18, 20, 20, 20, 20, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 46, 47, 47, 47, 49, 50, 50, 51, 51, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 55, 55, 55, 57, 59, 60, 60, 67, 68, 72, 74, 76, 76, 78, 79]
```

As you can see, this gives me length of each `title`, but I don't know the actual title. How can I also print the `title` alongside its length for each json object?

Comment: Using lambda expression in your `key= ` of `sorted`. like `sorted(payload, key = lambda x: len(x['title']))`.

Comment: @Heaven thank you it works :) can you please post it as an answer so i mark it as correct

Comment: No worries. Answering your doubts is enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to specify a custom sorting criterion:

```
d = sorted(payload, key=lambda x: len(x['title']))
print(d)
```

The official documentation actually has an example of sorting with a `lambda` here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Then, to print titles and their lengths, you could do something like:

```
titles = [(p['title'], len(p['title'])) for p in sorted(payload, key=lambda x: len(x['title']))]
print(titles)
>>> [('qui est esse', 12), ('sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit', 74)]
```

Comment: thank you, can you please see the last question as well?

Comment: @MaverickD updated. I assumed printing the title and their lengths as tuples would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

One could do it in three stages:

1) extract title

2) sort by len

3) build pairs

This still comfortably fits one line and is actually quite readable:

```
[(x, len(x)) for x in sorted((x['title'] for x in mock), key=len)]
```

Sample run

```
[('jfzq', 4), ('uqixc', 5), ('xparg', 5), ('uvuuk', 5), ('gsibnde', 7), ('pophwash', 8), ('cudisvgf', 8), ('swptewjg', 8), ('rthjtjylh', 9), ('ezvwpqhfn', 9)]
```

Code to create `mock` data:

```
>>> from random import choices, randint
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> 
>>> mock = [{k: ''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=randint(4, 10))) for k in ('userId', 'id', 'title', 'body')} for _ in range(10)]
```